# What's the boot folder in ESP?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, partitioning, uefi

[My partition table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXbD4.png)

First disk is for data, second for OS, in the last partition Ubuntu is installed. I had now completely shifted my whole workflow from windows 10 to ubuntu. And I was thinking to give ubuntu more space or in other words, remove my unactivated windows 10. And yes, my EFI partition's size was also small, so I wanna create a bigger one.

[EFI System Partition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXWuU.png)

In above picture, 'Microsoft' and 'Ubuntu' dirs are respectively for windows 10 and ubuntu, but what about boot directory, what's in it ? What's its purpose ? Is the UEFI firmware installed in it ? That is what stopped me from fully formating my SSD and installing ubuntu in it.

Any further guidance will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It usually just contains a fallback copy of some OS bootloader.

If the firmware does not have any boot entries stored in its NVRAM (or if all of them fail to start), it will instead launch the fallback bootloader located at `\EFI\Boot\BootX64.efi`. This is the primary method for booting from removable drives, and it's similar to how you would boot from "the disk" in BIOS era.

Usually this file is a copy of your regular bootloader – e.g. if you installed Windows last, it will probably be a copy of \EFI\Microsoft\Bootmgfw.efi and if you installed Ubuntu last, it might be a copy of grubx64.efi.

(The file name varies depending on CPU architecture, e.g. it would be `BootIA64.efi` on Itanium. See [UEFI Specification](https://uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/UEFI%20Spec%202.8B%20May%202020.pdf#page=159).)

Comment: So is it safe to format EFI partiton and create a new one when installing Ubuntu